# YouTube API v3: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I have an .Net web application which uploads a video to YouTube using the v3 API.    Everything was working fine before on the dev server.   Today I can't get a video to upload.   I get this error.

An error prevented the upload from completing.System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 377
An error prevented the upload from completing.System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: baseUri at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.d__e.MoveNext() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 459occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust

Any idea how to fix?   It seems like a connectivity issue between the dev server and Google servers.    I looked around and it sounded like the internet time wasn't synchronized, but I was able to do it in Windows on the server.

Comment: same code works on another web server in a different network.    Not sure what changed here.